# URL Mapping in grails, should not be display anything except root name

Tags: postgresql, grails

i have created small grails project now i wanns work on url mapping

my project name is Hellograils
path is localhost:8080/Hellograils

i created user authentication and registration using rest api
now i wanna display in url only root path except that no want to display any controller or action name

eg : localhost:8080/Hellograils/userlogin/passwordcheck 
insteatd of this url that should display only root path 
i.e localhost:8080/Hellograils 
if its not possible that should display like localhost:8080/Hellograils/users its should take only one word after root path how can i solve this one

Comment: now am doing in URLmapping.config but not working my code is
 
constraints {
// apply constraints here
"/user"(controller:"userpassword",action="passwordpage")
"/users"(controller:"userpassword",action="passwordpage/passwordvalidate")
            }

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do there but `action="passwordpage/passwordvalidate"` is not valid.

Comment: No i missed id there i.e type,name and id

Answer (score 1):

> eg : localhost:8080/Hellograils/userlogin/passwordcheck insteatd of
>   this url that should display only root path i.e
>   localhost:8080/Hellograils if its not possible that should display
>   like localhost:8080/Hellograils/users its should take only one word
>   after root path how can i solve this one

If your context root is `Hellograils` and you want the `passwordcheck` action in the `userlogin` controller to be associated with localhost:8080/Hellograils then you can do something like this in your url mappings:

```
"/"(controller: 'userlogin', action: 'passwordcheck')
```

If you want localhost:8080/Hellograils/user to be associated with that same action, you can do something like this:

```
"/user"(controller: 'userlogin', action: 'passwordcheck')
```

All of that assumes your controller name is `UserloginController` and the action name is `passwordcheck`.  More common convention is to use camel case so your controller name would be `UserLoginController` and the action name would be `passwordCheck`.  If you do use those names, then in the mapping you would need to use `userLogin` and `passwordCheck` instead of `userlogin` and `passwordcheck`.